# Local static server without trailing slash

Tags: configuration, server, localhost, trailing-slash, static-site

What's the simplest way to run a [static server without trailing slashes](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=168000) locally? Ideally, I'd simply like to only use tools that come installed with the latest version of OS X.

Unfortunately,

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

and

```
ruby -run -ehttpd . -p8000
```

both 301 redirect `/about` to `/about/`.

I want the opposite.

See more [static server one-liners](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255).

*Note*: My static site talks to a REST API that uses Rack.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has a better solution, use `Rack::Static`.

True, Rack doesn't come installed with the latest version of OS X, but you need it anyway to run the REST API that your static site talks to.

See [Heroku Dev Center: Creating Static Sites in Ruby with Rack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby).

Please update this answer with your completed code. Thanks!